# Read content from localhost with Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to read a simple Hello World and show it on a Text. Currently using Unity 2017, Visual Studio 2017 and Hololens.

This is the code I'm using to read the content from the localhost.

```
IEnumerator Desplegar(){
    WWW conexion = new WWW ("192.168.1.62:8080");
    yield return (conexion);

    string contenido = conexion.text;
    contenidoMesh.text = contenido;
    Debug.Log (contenido);
}
```

When I run it with Unity, It is able to find and show the content but with the Hololens It shows nothing.

I already have enabled all network capabilities.

Can anyone tell me how to read data and show it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check `www.error` and see if it has anything. If it is not null then post the error. That should be useful

Comment: Thaks! I already fixed it using an Apache server and some simple php. I was using node and javascript.

Comment: are u getting the log in console?